# javascript: execute jquery code variables by the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i don't know good title but heres the explain

i have this link

```
<a href="#" class="link" effect="show"> Link1 </a>
<a href="#" class="link" effect="fadeIn"> Link2 </a>
<a href="#" class="link" effect="slideDown"> Link2 </a>
```

i want if click `.link` use its effect meas

```
$('a').hide();
$('.link').click(function(){
     var effect = $(this).attr("effect");
     /* 
       what should i do here  not conditions to make if effect is show show this link
       if its fadeIn   do fade in  etc

      */
})  ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var effect = $(this).attr("effect");
$(this)[effect]();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sGWr5/

Comment: @Mark no, strictly it's taking advantage of the fact that object properties can only be accessed using variables using `a[prop]` syntax instead of `a.prop`.

Comment: note that, as written, you'll get a `TypeError` if `effect` is ever undefined

Comment: @Shad indeed - "don't do that" ;-)

Comment: @MonaAbdelmajeed you should use `data-xxx`, as recommended by @ninja

Comment: @Alnitak you could mitigate it with something simple like `var effect = $(this).attr('effect') || 'valueOf';`

Comment: @Shad I'd probably use `if (effect in $(this))`

Comment: @Alnitak oh nice, i always forget about non-`for` applications of that operator

Answer (score 1):

You can't just add your own attributes to a html element, its bad. HTML5 has support for this via the 'data' attribute. So if you got html5 support do something like shit:

```
<a href="#" class="link" data-effect="fadeIn"> Link1 </a>
```

Javascript

```
$('a.link').on('click', function() { 
    var effect = $(this).data('effect');
    switch(effect) {
       case 'fadeIn':
           $('elementtoshow').fadeIn();
       break;

       case 'show':
           $('elementtoshow').show();
       break;

       // etc
    }
});
```

If you really dont wanna use html5 for some reason, store the effect in the elements id, and grab it by:

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

instead.

Comment: Why would you suggest "id" as the alternative?

Comment: You can also validate with custom attributes if u add it to the DOCTYPE

Answer (score 0):

why are you using `$('a').hide();` ?  are you wanting to hide all the links once u click one of them?  if so this should work,  u just have the order wrong

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    var effect = $(this).attr("effect");
    $('a.link').hide();
    alert(effect);

})  ;
```

Comment: No sir , if i clicked any link it has effect(show,fadeIn,slideDown)  how to execute the effect function mean  if var effect result is show  i want to   show the link , if effect is fadeIn i want to fadeIn the link if its  slideDown  i want to slideDown the link  etc

Comment: but if they are hidden to begin with, how can u click them to create the effect?  you want them to LOAD when the page loads using the effect?

Comment: yes this was mistake from me , my code not like this example so i make this mistake if its hide where is click :)